# Can I add php_value magic_quotes_gpc off to .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

My current .htaccess has the following.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Can I add the following to .htaccess?

```
php_value include_path ".;C:/xampp/htdocs/phpweb20/include"
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
php_value register_globals off
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) being a boolean configuration, you should use `php_flag`, instead of `php_value`.

See [How to change configuration settings](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php), about that -- and note that it will only work if PHP is used as an Apache module, not as a CGI.

Considering [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) can be changed `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, it might work... Once again, if you are running PHP as an Apache module.

Then : did you try ? That's the best way of knowing, I'd say ;-)

If it's not working : it might depend on your hosting service -- maybe they have some support that could help you about that ?

For instance, with my hosting provider (ovh.com), which is running PHP as CGI, and not Apache module, I have to use something like this to activate `magic_quotes_gpc` -- which probably means the opposite to de-activate :

```
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 1
```

But that clearly depends on your hosting service...